# Request for GoalXXCompletions data should match Goal Completions (all) and GA UI but doesn't

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

When we make a request for `GoalXXCompletions` we get back the wrong number. The (higher) number doesn't match data shown in the Google Analytics reporting UI and it doesn't match data we get back when we request `Goal Completions (all)`. Only one goal in our GA account has data so we would expect to get back the same numbers for `GoalXXCompletions` as we do for `Goal Completions (all)`.

Notably we use `dateHour` format for `GoalXXCompletions` and `dateHourMinute` for `Goal Completions (all)`. How could this be causing a discrepancy?

Does anyone have experience with this issue?

Comment: please edit your question and include your code.  we need to see the code you are using to make the request and the exact request as well as the data you are comparing it to.

Comment: Wild guess without more details: **sampling** https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2637192?hl=en